# Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

the following SQL statement shows solid results with PRINT but with EXEC, gives me Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'

```
USE EPDB

DECLARE @Table as nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @Column as nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @Select as nvarchar(375)
DECLARE @Where as nvarchar(275)

SET @Table = 'TableABC'
SET @Column = 'ColumnABC'`enter code here`
SET @Select = 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'
SET @Where = 'CRITERIA = ''VALUE'''


-- EXEC ('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNSWHERETABLE_NAME = ' + @Table + '''')

PRINT @Select + ' WHERE ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Where,'CRITERIA','TABLE_NAME'),'VALUE',@Table)

EXEC (@Select + ' WHERE ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Where,'CRITERIA','TABLE_NAME'),'VALUE',@Table))
```

not sure what is going on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @sSQL varchar(1000)

SET @sSQL = @Select + ' WHERE ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Where,'CRITERIA','TABLE_NAME'),'VALUE',@Table)

EXEC (@sSQL)
```

I believe EXEC() accepts either string variable or a string constant, but not combination.

Comment: i have seen SQL that combines them together but it seems that for our installation ( we are still running SQL2005 ) combining is not gonna fly; thank you Yuri

Comment: Glad it worked for you. And I think you're correct and the concatenation became possible in later versions.

Comment: No, still invalid syntax in SQL Server 2012 and 2014